# xml 'data-block' and validating schema

Tags: xml, xsd, block

I was wondering the what the best way to validate a data block in an xsd schema the data is as follows

```
<dataBlock>
    <blockParameters>        
        <dataType>TEMP</dataType>   
        <Property index="1">
            <propertyData name="dataRef">
            <typeData>decimal</typeData>
            <propertydescritption>reading reference</propertydescritption>
            <nullValue>-999</nullValue>
            </propertyData>
        </Property>
        <Property index="2">
            <propertyData name="dataType">
                <typeData>string</typeData>
                <propertydescritption>Reading type</propertydescritption>                       
                <nullValue>-999</nullValue>
            </propertyData>
        </Property>
        <Property index="3">
            <propertyData name="dataDtim">
                <typeData>datetime</typeData>
                <propertydescritption>Date and time of reading</propertydescritption>
                <uom>DateTime</uom>
                <nullValue>-999</nullValue>
            </propertyData>
        </Property>
        <Property index="4">
            <propertyData name="dataRdng">
                <typeData>float</typeData>
                <propertydescritption>data reading</propertydescritption>
                <uom>#degC</uom>
                <nullValue>-999</nullValue>
            </propertyData>
        </Property>
        <Property index="5">
            <propertyData name="dataRem">
                <typeData>string</typeData>
                <propertydescritption>Comments on reading</propertydescritption>                       
                <nullValue>-999</nullValue>
            </propertyData>
        </Property>    
    </blockParameters>
    <tokenSeparator>&#x20;</tokenSeparator>
    <blockSeparator>,</blockSeparator>
    <decimalSeparator>.</decimalSeparator>
    <data>
        1 TEMP 1999-05-03T11:45 19.4 basereading,
        2 TEMP 1999-05-04T12:00 19.6 -999,
        3 TEMP 1999-05-05T11:45 21.8 -999,
        4 TEMP 1999-05-06T11:30 26.6 -999,
        5 TEMP 1999-05-07T11:00 24.6 -999,
        6 TEMP 1999-05-08T12:45 24.5 -999,
        7 TEMP 1999-05-09T12:00 25.9 -999,
        8 TEMP 1999-05-10T11:45 21 -999,
        9 TEMP 1999-05-11T12:00 19.8 -999,
        10 TEMP 1999-05-12T11:45 20.7 -999,
        11 TEMP 1999-05-13T11:30 21.3 -999,
        12 TEMP 1999-05-14T11:00 22.5 -999,
        13 TEMP 1999-05-15T12:45 22.6 -999,
        14 TEMP 1999-05-16T12:00 21.1 -999,
        15 TEMP 1999-05-17T11:45 23.6 -999,
        16 TEMP 1999-05-18T12:00 24.5 -999,
        17 TEMP 1999-05-19T11:45 24.1 -999,
        18 TEMP 1999-05-20T11:30 27.8 -999,
        19 TEMP 1999-05-21T11:00 23.8 -999,
        20 TEMP 1999-05-22T12:45 33.1 -999,
        21 TEMP 1999-05-23T12:00 21 -999,
        22 TEMP 1999-05-24T11:45 21.9 -999,
    </data>
</dataBlock>
```

I'm familiar with basic schema writing but I'm not sure how to represent this particular style of data representation.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about validating the text in the <data> element?  You could create a Pattern (regular expression) to validate it, but it's not the easiest to implement and debug.

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for a pattern to validate <data> because it looks like the block parameters above it is a "schema" of sorts for the data block.

Comment: OP, what have you tried?  Why is it lacking?  Are you looking for a schema to describe the entire snippet you've  posted, or are you looking for how to translate your <blockParameters> into schema?  It looks fairly straightforward to turn this entire block into schema.  So we'd like to see what you've done so we're not just writing the schema for you.